# Adding a custom directory to Info

Tags: init-file, info

I wanted to add `~/.emacs.d/custom-info/` to Info directories, where I’d link some locally installed programs’ documentation (like AsynK.io).

```
(add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list
  (expand-file-name "./custom-info/" user-emacs-directory))
```

The directory is added, as expected:

```
Info-default-directory-list
("/home/m/.emacs.d/custom-info/" "/usr/share/info/" "/usr/share/info/")
```

However, there’s no AsynK entry in `C-h i`, while:

```
% cat ~/.emacs.d/custom-info/asynk.info| grep -A2 'START-INFO-DIR-ENTRY'
START-INFO-DIR-ENTRY
* ASynk: (asynk).               Contacts synchronization.
END-INFO-DIR-ENTRY
%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you forget to update the `dir` file in your `~/.emacs.d/custom-info/ `? see http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Installing-Dir-Entries.html to learn how to do that.

Comment: @xuchunyang, thank you, I didn’t know I was supposed to do this. Now everything works.

Comment: @xuchunyang: Please post your comment as an answer. Michal: please consider accepting it. The question is a good one, and can help others if it is marked as answered etc.

Comment: @Drew, sure, I’m happy to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to install an Info file in a custom directory, in addition to telling your Info Reader where that directory is, you need to create/update `dir` file under that directory with `install-info` program (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Installing-Dir-Entries.html) to learn how to do it).